# Ito integral and true martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Consider a twice diferentiable function $F$ on $R$ with bounded
first derivative $F'$ and a Brownian motion $W$. Show that $F(W_t)-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} F'' (W_s)ds$ is a true martingale.

I tried do show it using this, but I only got confused and did not find any solution.

1. If $M$ is a local martingale with continues trajectories, then it is a true martingale and $E(M_t^2) < \infty$ for all $t\geq 0$
   Or
2. If $M$ is a local martingale with continues trajectories, then it is a true martingale and $E([M]_t)<\infty$ for all t.

Comment: I'm not sure where your statements 1 and 2 came from, but I don't think they're true in general.  A local martingale with continuous trajectories does not have to be a true martingale.  There is a standard example [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/local-martingales/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ were twice continuously differentiable, one could use Ito's Lemma to obtain the stochastic differential equation for $Y_t = F(W_t)$ as

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}Y_t = \frac{1}{2}F^{\prime \prime}(W_t) \mathrm{d}t + F^\prime(W_t) \mathrm{d}W_t.
\end{equation}

It follows that
\begin{equation}
F(W_t)-\int_0^t \frac{1}{2}F^{\prime \prime}(W_s) \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t F^\prime(W_s)\mathrm{d}W_s,
\end{equation}
which is clearly a martingale as $F^\prime$ is bounded.

If $F^{\prime \prime}$ is not continuous, I am not sure the assertion holds anymore.